# FFImageLoading some png's URL does not show image while some other show image

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

I try to use FFImageLoading for my Xamarin.Android application.
Everything works fine with URLs took from the Sample project on this Github.
But when I use personnal URLs pictures, nothing is showing :-(

Here is the code I use:

```
            //This one works fine
            string sURL = @"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Lfgi-xEMwuk/VNWoy8EDWcI/AAAAAAAAACk/rwsluNfhSZY/w1486-h832-no/photo.jpg";

            //This one does not work
            string sURL = @"http://api.moovenow.com/v1/fr_fr/images_public/user/140.png";

            ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(sURL)
            .Retry(3, 1000)
            .Error(ero =>
           {
                ;
            })
            .Success(() =>
            {
                ;
            })
            .Into(imageView);
```

When I debug, it goes through Success method each time.
But with the URL "140.png", the imageview has no image. It's like the image was transparent.

Edit: 
I tried with HTTPS. The result is the same.
I asked to the API developer if user-agent were required. They told me that no user-agent are needed to use the API.

Also, I noticed this line in my debug output logs:

```
--- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

Do you think it can be the source of my problem?

Answer (score 1):

See from Github : 
https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/533#issuecomment-285485970

The problem is that the URL return a GZIP encoded PNG.

With the same URL, if GZIP is deactivated, FFImageLoading is working. 
But when GZIP is activated, FFImageLoading show nothing.